# Dependency property in custom control is sharing memory/values unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have the following set up:

- Custom WPF Control (Base class), deriving from `Canvas`
- Implementation of that base class
- An `ObservableCollection<T>` dependency property on that implementation

I have a test app that displays three unique instances of my custom control (e.g. `<custom:MyControl x:Name="Test1" />`, Test2, Test3, and so on). When I run and debug the app, the contents of the `ObservableCollection<T>` are the same for all three instances of the control. Why is this?

---

Chart:

```
[ContentProperty("DataGroups")]
public abstract class Chart : Canvas
{
    static Chart()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Chart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Chart)));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChartData> DataGroups
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ChartData>)GetValue(DataGroupsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataGroupsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGroupsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataGroups", typeof(ObservableCollection<ChartData>), typeof(Chart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ChartData>(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

    public abstract void Refresh();
}
```

ChartData:

```
[ContentProperty("Points")]
public class ChartData : FrameworkElement
{
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Point>)GetValue(PointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Points", typeof(ObservableCollection<Point>), typeof(ChartData), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Point>()));
}
```

---

One way I modify the chart data is (assuming multiple data groups), for example:

```
MyChart.DataGroups[index].Points.Add(new Point() { Y = someNumber });
MyChart.Refresh();
```

But every instance inside `DataGroups[]` is identical.

---

The same thing is happening if I define my collection(s) via XAML, like so:

```
<c:Chart x:Name="ChartA">
    <c:ChartData x:Name="DataGroup1" />
    <c:ChartData x:Name="DataGroup2" />
</c:Chart>
```

Then, in code, I would access the defined collections:

```
ChartA.DataGroups[0].Points.Add(new Point() { Y = someNumber });
ChartA.Refresh();
```

Comment: You have to show us some code. What does the dependency property declaration look like? How are you binding it?

Comment: Code added, though it's very partial (I tried to extract the relevant bits as best I could, I can't just paste it all in here because the implementation is huge, and a lot of it is irrelevant).

Comment: Where does `Points` come from? How does it get assigned?

Comment: The bottom of the question explains both where it's defined and how it gets assigned, though it is just as likely that it could be assigned through XAML as it is through code (because of the `[ContentProperty]` attribute). And `Point` is just `System.Windows.Point`.

Comment: So if you have `Test1.Points = new ObservableCollection<Point>(); Test2.Points = new ObservableCollection<Point>(); Test1.Points.Add(new Point());` then `Test2.Points` will have the same point as added to `Test1`?

Comment: No, despite the fact that dependency properties are static, their backing properties are not, and you would typically not set the `Points` property like that anyway, because in the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` you specify a default value, which I set to `new ObservableCollection<Point>()` anyway. Also, the points are not the only things that are being duplicated, there are other (not shown) properties in `ChartData` that are also being duplicated. It's basically the `public ObservableCollection<ChartData> DataGroups` that's acting "static" even though it isn't.

Comment: OK, well there's your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You havent done anything wrong. It is by design. It shall work that way. Just set your value in constructor instead and you will not have a singleton.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx

Initializing the Collection Beyond the Default Value

When you create a dependency property, you do not specify the property default value as the initial field value. Instead, you specify the default value through the dependency property metadata. If your property is a reference type, the default value specified in dependency property metadata is not a default value per instance; instead it is a default value that applies to all instances of the type. Therefore you must be careful to not use the singular static collection defined by the collection property metadata as the working default value for newly created instances of your type. Instead, you must make sure that you deliberately set the collection value to a unique (instance) collection as part of your class constructor logic. Otherwise you will have created an unintentional singleton class.

Comment: Perfect, that solved it. I was not aware that was how dependency property default values worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`PointsProperty` is a static value that you initialize with a default value of `new ObservableCollection<Point>()`. This static initializer creates a single `ObservableCollection` and uses that as the default value for `Points` on any object of type `ChartData` that you create. It is not a factory that creates new `ObservableCollection`s for every instance that needs a default value; it simply uses the same `ObservableCollection` for each.

I'm guessing that you never explicitly assign a value to `Points`, thus always relying on the default value, which is shared across all instances. That's why each instance has the same collection of points.

Comment: You were both right, but I went with the underdog with 200 points instead of 44,000 points. Hope you understand. :) Thanks for your help!