# Dependency Property Cross-Contamination in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a WPF DataGrid that is bound to a collection.  One of the DataGrid's columns is DataGridTemplateColumn containing my custom control:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="$ Diff" Width="60*">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ui:BoardValueDifference Board1="{Binding Board1}" Board2="{Binding Board2}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My custom control has two Dependency Properties, Board1 and Board2, pretty standard stuff.

```
public BoardValueDifference()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty Board1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Board1", typeof(PackageBoard),
        typeof(BoardValueDifference), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDataChanged));

public PackageBoard Board1
{
    get { return (PackageBoard)GetValue(Board1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Board1Property, value); }
}

protected static void OnDataChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{
    BoardValueDifference bvd = d as BoardValueDifference;

    if ( bvd != null )
        bvd.CalculateDifference();
}

protected void CalculateDifference()
{
    if ( Board1 != null && Board2 != null) {
        // Calculate value difference between boards
    }
}
```

My issue is that Board1 and Board2 appear to be indeterminate, I'm getting values from other rows.  If I put a breakpoint in OnDataChanged() I'll see it hit by the Board1's databinding, then by Board2's databinding, but in-between Board2 will have values from other rows, it's especially bad if I scroll up and down my DataGrid.

From another Question I found this link, [Collection-Type Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903961(VS.95).aspx), which isn't specific to my case but seems similar.  They suggest SetValue() in the constructor and setting the default value of the property to a new instance.  I tried setting it to null but it seemed to completely disable my data binding.

```
SetValue(Board1Property, null);
```

My guess is that because DependencyProperties are static, and because my DependencyProperty is a class there's some sort of sharing going on between instances of my BoardValueDifference user control.  How do I fix this?  I think it may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217208/dependency-property-in-custom-control-is-sharing-memory-values-unexpectedly) but I'm not understanding the responses well enough to fix my case.

### Update

After adding some logging to my UserControl, I think I see what is going on:

1. I had assumed that each row of the DataGrid would get a new instance of my UserControl and Board1 and Board2 would start off null.  According to my log, BoardValueDifference is getting re-used instead, with just the DependencyProperties being changed.
2. In my code, I was calculating the difference between boards once both Board1 and Board2 were no longer null.  I realize I can't do that now, but it feels very sloppy to have leftover data in my UserControl.  I guess you have to think of it more like a static class?

Bottom line, I can work around this, but I would appreciate it if anyone has a better workaround or knows exactly how the lifecycle of a UserControl in a DataGrid is supposed to work.

Comment: What's the reason for using `PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` instead of directly registering a PropertyChangedCallback with `PropertyMetadata` passed to `DependencyProperty.Register`?

Comment: No specific reason, I switched between the two methods at one point while trying to solve this bug and didn't go back.  If I remember correctly the way I have it here [can lead to a memory leak?](http://sharpfellows.com/post/Memory-Leaks-and-Dependency-Properties)

Comment: Use a PropertyChangedCallback. This other method is just weird.

Comment: Changed to make you happy, has nothing to do with root issue though, same issue either way.

Comment: One more thing, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Board1 and Board2 bindings doesn't make sense. It's only effective on two-way bindings.

Comment: That said, your problem hasn't got anything to with the problem in the other SO question. The type of your proberty isn't a collection (I guess) and, more important, you're not assigning a default value by property metadata.

Comment: I finally added some logging and what I'm seeing doesn't make any sense to me, one of my basic assumptions about custom UserControls must be wrong:
1. I am assuming that each row in the DataGrid would get a new unique instance of my UserControl
2. Each unique instance of my UserControl class would get that row's data.

What I am seeing looks more like
1. My UserControl is getting re-used/recycled
2. When new rows come into view it just updates the Dependency Properties instead of creating new instances of my control

Comment: I don't see the registration of Board2Property. I suppose it should be just like Board1, but if you cut and paste and leave a Board1 in there somewhere, you will get things mixed up. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserControls are recycled due to row virtualization. If there aren't too many rows in your DataGrid you could disable this behavior by setting the `EnableRowVirtualization` property to false.

From the Remarks section on the [DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization(v=vs.110).aspx) page:

> To improve performance, the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to
>   true by default. When the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to
>   true, the DataGrid does not instantiate a DataGridRow object for each
>   data item in the bound data source. Instead, the DataGrid creates
>   DataGridRow objects only when they are needed, and reuses them as much
>   as it can. For example, the DataGrid creates a DataGridRow object for
>   each data item that is currently in view and recycles the row when it
>   scrolls out of view.

Comment: Unfortunately I have over 3,000 rows and need the virtualization, do you know if there is a way to have it nullify the DependencyProperty when swapping to a new row?  I have already tried setting the default value on the FrameworkPropertyMetadata to null and that didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You could try if the `Unloaded` event is fired when the UserControl is recycled. Another approach might be to have only one property which already holds the difference between Board1 and Board2. You would bind it to both the Board1 and Board2 source properties by a MultiBinding with a multi-value converter that calculates the difference.